# Cyclic dependency error with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
        var newsfeed = db.collection('newsfeed');
        newsfeed.findAndModify({
            _id: mongodb.ObjectId(newsfeedId)
        }, {
            new: true
        }, {
            $set: newsfeed
        }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            } else {
                return resolve(result.value);
            }
        });
```

I get a cyclic dependency error when i run this query on mongodb, ive read through other solutions presented in stackoverflow but cant seem to fix this error ..
this is the error message i see
[image]

Comment: `new:true` must be after `$set`

Comment: @sidgate that didnt work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are setting the newsfeed object back to newsfeed collection. Try to include the field which needs to be updated instead of whole object.

Comment: i cant believe i didnt see that , thanks a lot . worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

you may added some schema restrictions on model with type

try to console the `newsfeed` and make sure data you are trying to update matching with schema field type